# Mongoose update or updateMany to sub document returned same ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I just want to know. Is it true that the results from update or updateMany appearing on the subdocument will produce the same ObjectId?

Is there an error from my query or is this a bug from mongoose / mongodb?

There is my mongoose query to push data using update or updateMany

Using update:

```
const announcement = await Team.update({}, {
    $push: {
       announcements: {desc}
    }}, {multi: true, runValidators: true});

if(announcement.nModified === 0) throw new Error('');

res.send(announcement);
next();
```

Using updateMany:

```
const announcement = await Team.updateMany({}, {
    $push: {
       announcements: {desc}
    }}, {runValidators: true});

if(announcement.nModified === 0) throw new Error('');

res.send(announcement);
next();
```

And this is a result in mongodb document:

```
team: [
    {
        "name": "team 1"
        "announcements": [
            {
                "_id": "5cdd0bd9cc45120426c89f1c",
                "desc" : "test"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "team 2"
        "announcements": [
            {
                "_id": "5cdd0bd9cc45120426c89f1c",
                "desc" : "test"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "team 3"
        "announcements": [
            {
                "_id": "5cdd0bd9cc45120426c89f1c",
                "desc" : "test"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

as you see. When I run the query, it will generate new data that will be pushed into the 'announcements' subdocument. But strangely, their ObjectId is all the same.

Is it really like this? or a bug? or my query is wrong?

Comment: What is data type for announcements._id ?

Comment: ObjectId() ....